# Checkstyle not detecting @throws tag

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

Checkstyle keeps giving me this error:

> Expected @throws tag for RemoteException

This is my javadoc comments and first line of method:

```
   /**
     * Inits the filter
     *
     * @throws RemoteException if there is an issue
     */

    public void init() throws RemoteException {
```

Comment: Please share the configuration that you are using to run Checkstyle.

Answer (score 6):

If you have not added description for the exception, try adding it.
That worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Really hope this helps someone:

```
/*
* @throws SomeExceptionPresentOnImports             some text
* @throws com.myorg.SomeExceptionPresentOnImports1  some text
*/
```

Both are reported as errors

but if you remove the fully qualified names it will not complain.

```
/*
* @throws SomeExceptionPresentOnImports   some text
* @throws SomeExceptionPresentOnImports1  some text
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

A late answer that worked for me is to add an extra space after the exception in the javaDoc comment:

```
    /**
     * ...... 
     * @throws DummyException (notice the extra space in this line)
     * ......
     */
```

Answer (score 1):

Using
"* @throws IOException - IOException"
instead of  just
"* @throws IOException"
worked for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up modifying my checkstyle configuration file:

```
<module name="JavadocMethod">
  <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
</module>
```